# Custom return in Asp.net Core Web API

Tags: asp.net, api, graphql

I have a basic question about returning the ASP.NET core web API standard DDD.
We have a service and validations with fluentvalidation. How do I return SiteDto in case of success and alert messages in case the registration already exists? What is the correct way to do this?

```
public class SiteService : ISiteService
{
    private IRepositoryBase<NcSite> _repository;

    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public SiteService(MyContext context, IRepositoryBase<NcSite> repository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _context = context;
    }


    public async Task<SiteDto> Create(SiteDtoCreate site)
    {
        string returnValidator = string.Empty;

        var model = _mapper.Map<SiteModel>(site);                 

        //Validações com fluentvalidation
        var validator = new SiteDtoValidator(Operator.Create);
        var validRes = validator.Validate(model);
        if (!validRes.IsValid)
        {  
            returnValidator = string.Join(", ", validRes.Errors).ToString();
            return null;                
        }

        //Verifica se Site ja existe com o nome
        var id = GetQuery().Where(x => x.Nome.Equals(site.Nome)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (id != null)
        {
            returnValidator = "Site já cadastrado.";               
            return null;
        }
       
        var entity = _mapper.Map<NcSite>(model);                      
        var result = await _repository.InsertAsync(entity);            
        return _mapper.Map<SiteDto>(result);                            
    }       
}
```

Comment: If there's a validation error like that you could return a Bad Request response which could then contain error messages. That's how you end up returning a different structure than the intended model. Having the different Http status is also useful as it signals to the caller that they should expect to deserialise a different structure